# 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'touch'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Does anyone know what is the problem with this code? it's for a unity basic game. the error says 'Input' does not contain a definition for 'touch'. btw I don't have any file called Input

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{   
private Touch touch;
private float speedModifier;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    speedModifier = 0.01f;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touch > 0)
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
        transform.position = new Vector3(
            transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
            transform.position.y,
            transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the type of `Input` you're referring to in your code? The compiler is telling you that that object doesn't have a `touch` property

Comment: @RufusL most probably [`Input`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) ;)  ... => @OP well, it doesn't ...  please simply look into the API and use one of the existing fields/properties instead ^^ Also please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your

```
if (Input.touch > 0)
```

to

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
```

as the error message says, there is no definition for `Input.touch`, but you want to have that if statement to make sure that `Input.GetTouch(0)` does not return a null

Comment: you are welcome. if it answered your question and you don't have any other problems please accept the answer